# Setup for an uploader (carrierwave)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, file-upload, carrierwave

I have an image uploader in place following a tutorial using the gems carrierwave and fog. Now I would like to add an additional uploader but am struggling.

I have generated the uploader (`rails generate uploader name`). In the model file I have mounted the uploader to the right column (`mount_uploader :column_name, nameUploader`). In the uploader itself I have set `def extension_white_list` and `store_dir`. Also I included (since in the tutorial I did the same):

```
if Rails.env.production?
  storage :fog
else
  storage :file
end
```

Now where I'm stuck is that I don't know where to set the specifications for fog. That is, where to specify the Amazon bucket it should upload to. In a carrier_wave initializer I already had the code below. But this code specifies where to upload to for the uploader I had already implemented. These specifications are different for this new uploader. Where/how should I include these specs for the new uploader?

```
if Rails.env.production?   
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.fog_credentials = {
      :provider              => 'AWS',
      :aws_access_key_id     => ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY'],
      :aws_secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET_KEY'],
      :region                => ENV['AWS_REGION']
    }
    config.fog_directory     =  ENV['S3_BUCKET']
  end 
end
```

Comment: The image itself is not a model, you would have to use the Uploader in a model like so:
   `class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
  belongs_to :organization
end`

Comment: I actually do have an Image model, which is associated with the Organization model. So `organization_id` is one of the columns in the Organization model. In the organizations controller, the `new` method calls upon the `upload_file` method in the Image model. The follow-up question basically is how to save the `organization_id` (which the controller method already passes to the model method) in the appropriate column of the Image model. I think the best way is to do this in the model method. But what excactly should I add for this to the mentioned model method?

Comment: Thanks @axel, I have posted a follow-up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31594988/4499505

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By looking at [this wiki page](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Define-different-storage-configuration-for-each-Uploader.)
it seems like it is possible to override the config for each uploader

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :fog

  # define some uploader specific configurations in the initializer
  # to override the global configuration
  def initialize(*)
    super

    self.fog_credentials = {
      :provider               => 'AWS',              # required
      :aws_access_key_id      => 'YOURAWSKEYID',     # required
      :aws_secret_access_key  => 'YOURAWSSECRET',    # required
    }
    self.fog_directory = "YOURBUCKET"
  end
end
```