# Uploader produces errors regarding the column in which it should store the path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, amazon-s3, carrierwave

An Image model has a 1:1 association with an Organization model. In the organizations controller, the `create` method calls on an Image model method called `upload_file`.

```
def create
  @organization = Organization.new(new_params)
  if @organization.save
    Image.upload_file(@organization.id)
  end
end
```

The `upload_file` method uses a carrierwave uploader to store a standard file in an Amazon S3 bucket. To this end, the Image model includes `mount_uploader :file_name, ImageUploader`.

My question is how to create an Image instance for the uploaded file? The path to the stored file should be stored in the column `file_name` in the Image model. And the organization associated with the image should be stored in the column `organization_id` in the Image model. How can I do this? More specifically, what code should I add for this to the model method below? (also see the comments in the method below.

```
def self.upload_file(organization_id)
  file = 'app/assets/emptyfile.xml'
  uploader = ImageUploader.new
  uploader.store!(file)
  # Am I correct to assume that the previous line uploads the file using the uploader, but does not yet create an Image record?
  # If so, then perhaps the next line should be as follows?:
  # Image.create!(organization_id: organization_id, filename: file.public_url)
  # I made up "file.public_url". What would be the correct code to include the path that the uploader stored the image at (in my case an Amazon S3 bucket)?
end
```

Currently in `rails console` I get the following error:

```
>> uploader = ImageUploader.new
=> #<ImageUploader:0x00000005d24f88 @model=nil, @mounted_as=nil, @fog_directory=nil>
>> file = 'app/assets/emptyfile.xml'
=> "app/assets/emptyfile.xml"
>> uploader.store!(file)
CarrierWave::FormNotMultipart: CarrierWave::FormNotMultipart
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/cache.rb:120:in `cache!'
  etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to call the uploader yourself. Carrierwave comes with a mechanism to do the uploading and storing in AR models for you:

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

Then you can do

```
u = Organization.new
u.image = params[:file] # Assign a file like this, or

# like this
File.open('somewhere') do |f|
  u.image = f
end

u.save!
u.image.url # => '/url/to/file.png'

u.image.current_path # => 'path/to/file.png'
u.image # => 'file.png'
```

Please visit the carrierwave [README](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) for more extensive examples.

Comment: Thanks Axel, I think I looked at a wrong section in the documentation, because `store!` is also a carrierwave method but in another section. I tried the following in the console: `uploader = ImageUploader.new` `File.open('app/assets/emptyfile.xml') do |f|` `uploader.file_name = f` `end` `uploader.save!`. This however produces the error: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'file_name=' for #<ImageUploader:0x00000005cc1bb8>`. Also, this would not yet save the organization_id for the image instance it creates.

Comment: Please do not use the Uploader directly. It is just wrong for your usecase. When mounting an uploader as shown above you get the 'image=' method as shown above. Your organiziation will have an image itself to access it. So you do not have to store the organization_id 'in the image'.

Comment: You are still creating new instances of the ImageUploader yourself - that's not how you are supposed to use the Uploader in conjunction with AR models

Comment: Use the code in my example above (notice the absence of ImageUploader.new..)

Comment: Ah, I see, making progress (updated the update in the post). I have a validation that before implementing the uploader, was working: `errors.add(:file_name, "File format error") unless (file_name.match(/\.xml\z/i))`. This validation now produces an error: `NoMethodError (undefined method 'match' for #<ImageUploader:0x007fe87b8ce770>)`. Is it looking at the uploaded file not as a file but as a string perhaps?

Comment: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/carrierwave/CarrierWave/Uploader/ExtensionWhitelist