# Carrierwave + Cloudfront + Signeed URLs + Multiple Buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, carrierwave, amazon-cloudfront

I have a Rails 5 app using `carrierwave`, `carrierwave-aws` and the `cloudfront-signer` gems.  I gave a default bucket configured for Carrierwave.  I can upload and serve content fine (i.e. user avatars etc.).

I have another uploader which has a dynamic bucket (i.e. per client) to segregate data.  I can upload no problem.  The problem is that these files won't serve over cloudfront (403 Forbidden).  I suspect it that the base CW config is trying to sign the buckets using the other bucket to access the files.

Here is my uploaded config that I tried so far:

```
  def initialize(*)
    super

    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31589872/setup-for-an-uploader-carrierwave

        self.aws_credentials = {
          region: ENV['AWS_REGION']
        }

        self.aws_bucket = Apartment::Tenant.current
        self.aws_signer = -> (unsigned_url, options) { Aws::CF::Signer.sign_url unsigned_url, options }

  end
```

It sets the custom bucket but the URLs seem to fail.  They are signed but all return 403.

I suspect I need to feed the aws_signer options the bucket or endpoint to make this work.

Any ideas?